# $T: V \to V$ is a linear transformation such that $\operatorname{Range}(T)=\operatorname{Nullspace}(T)$. Which of the following is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional non-zero vector space $\mathbb C$ and $T: V \to V$ is a linear transformation such that $\operatorname{Range}(T)=\operatorname{Nullspace}(T)$. Then which of the following is true?
>
> 1. The dimension of $V$ is even.
> 2. $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$
> 3. Both $0$ and $1$ are the eigenvalues of $T$.
> 4. $T^2=0$

I really have no idea how to approach this problem. Can someone please help me figure out how to solve the problem?

Comment: A suggestion for writing questions: Even if you *really have no idea how to approach*, you could always mention the relevant definitions/theorems you know. This helps the reader understand how much you know and help you accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

$(a)$ follows from Rank-Nullity theorem.
Next, try to show $T^2=0$ from the given condition, which will show $(b)$ is true but $(c)$ is not.

Comment: Rank Nullity Theorem is for $T$ and not $V$.

Comment: Yes, Rank-Nullity theorem for $T$.

Comment: Option (a) talks about the dimension of $V$.

Comment: Yes, if you know the Rank Nullity theorem then once you right it on the notebook.